# Python - populate treeview from list of file paths in Python / Pyside

Tags: python, file, tree, pyside

I'm quite new to pyside and I'm trying to populate a tree in pyside based on a path list.

this :

```
/home/pi/folder
/home/pi/folder/file.txt
/home/pi/folder/test/
/home/pi/folder/test/file2.txt
...
```

Should be shown on a tree like thins

```
+---home
|   |
|   +------pi
|          |
|          +------ folder
|                 |
|                 +------file.txt
|                 |
|                 +------ test
|                          |
|                          +--- file2.txt
 ...
```

I have no idea where to start with. A QTreeView with a custom model ? A QTreeWidget ?

Your help would be much apprecied.

Thanks in advance.

Victorien

**EDIT :**
With a QTree Items could be added like this with a QStandardItemModel

```
def addItems(self, parent, elements):

    for text, children in elements:
        item = QStandardItem(text)
        parent.appendRow(item)
        if children:
            self.addItems(item, children)
```

So I need to transform my path list to a list of tupe like this :

```
 [("home", [("pi", [("folder", [("file.txt", []), ("test", [("file2.txt", [])])])])])]
```